# Erro: 'ExecuteReader: propriedade Connection não foi inicializada.'

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-select

Preciso fazer um acesso a um banco de dados onde eu mesmo coloco os dados, a parte de inserção esta funcionando, mas agora preciso "pegar" o dado novamente quando eu clico no botão, so que nao importa o modo que eu faço sempre da essa mensagem de erro:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader: propriedade Connection não foi inicializada.'

Meu codigo esta nessa forma:

```
public void RetornaUser(string Service)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Logins WHERE Servico = @Service AND Estado = @Estado");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Servico", Service);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", Estado);
    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (leitor.Read())
    {
        //passo os valores para o objeto cliente 
        //que será retornado 
        string Login = leitor["Login"].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(Login);
    }

    //fecha conexão 
    con.Close();
}
```

Caso queiram ver todo o codigo esta [AQUI](https://github.com/HigorAlves/Social-Exchanger)

No caso eu queria saber como eu faço para retirar os dados e passar para uma variavel para que minha função retorne para a outra os dados da conta para que ela possa usar.

Answer (score 1):

Como a própria mensagem de erro diz, a propriedade `Connection` não foi incializada.

Toda e qualquer instância de [`SqlCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) **precisa** ter a conexão definida.

Isso pode ser feito no próprio [construtor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/877h0y3a(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * From Logins", connection);
```

ou "*settando*" o valor da propriedade

```
sqlCommand.Connection = connection;
```

Então, apenas adapte seu código para ter definir uma conexão em `SqlCommand`.

Ex.:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Logins WHERE Condicao", connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom galera, consegui achar o erro estava faltando uma pequena linha de codigo para que eu pudesse realizar a conexão:

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

Tinha me esquecido de referir a qual conexão eu estaria buscando.

Agora meu codigo esta assim:

```
public void RetornaUser(string Service)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Logins WHERE Servico = @Service AND Estado = @Estado");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Service", Service);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", Estado);
    con.Open();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    SqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (leitor.Read())
    {
        //passo os valores para o objeto cliente 
        //que será retornado 
        string Login = leitor["Login"].ToString();
        string Senha = leitor["Senha"].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("Login:"+Login+"\nSenha:"+Senha);
    }

    //fecha conexão 
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: não esqueça de marcar a sua resposta como a correta